# Does RUBY on RAILS 4.0.2 work with MS SQL Server Express?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server-express

I've googled this to death and I'm just going around in circles.
I'm on a Windows Server 2008r 
I installed and put the following in my Gemfile

```
gem 'ruby-odbc' # I think the version is the.9999 one?

gem 'tiny_tds', "~> 0.6.1"

gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter' # I've tried a few versions of this 3.2.8 and 4.0
```

I get varying errors depending on how many times i've bundle installed or updated

Errors include activesupport and activerecord versions not found. They are installed
Or I get alias_method errors.

Can someone just point me in the right direction of what I should do. Some discussions seem to think that there is nothing that works at the moment. Would downgrading to an older Rails work? If so how and which version?

Comment: Can you also list the version of the Gems you're using/trying to use.

Comment: @vee - updated my question - is that what you meant? or do you want to see the whole gemfile? because it's the standard. i haven't added/altered anything else

Comment: What error do you get most of the times when you run: `bundle install`?

Comment: error first occurs after I try to run: rails generate model testtable name:string description:text.... alias_method undefined in class 'add order!'

Comment: same thing happens if i try to get to rails console

Answer (score 0):

activerecord-sqlserver-adapter hasn't been released for Rails 4.0 yet but the gem is 95% ready.  You can use put it in your Gemfile like this:

```
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', github: 'rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
```

For a description of the outstanding work take a look at [Failed Tests & Segfault](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/pull/298) on this pull request.